# Como tranferir dados de um objeto para outra no react?

Tags: react

Estou recebeno os dados de um serviço via API. gostaria de pegar esse resultado e dar um set em outra variavel. mas como mostra nas fotos. eu recebo o objeto certinho, mas quando tento tranferir o resultado para a variavel cliente não mostra.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7XPP.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azb8G.png)
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heyo6.png)

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o console.log está sendo executado antes do dado ser setado no state, por isso da a impressão que não foi setado, coloca esse console.log dentro de um useEffect observando o state cliente, ele será disparado quando o state for atualizado.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Client-->", cliente)
}, [cliente])
```